# Geometric intersection in Django's GEOS API no longer working

Tags: python, django, geometry, geos

I've been using Django's GEOS API for a while and it's worked great. I upgraded something in my project and some code I had which determines if points are within a polygon no longer works. I've distilled it down to this, which demonstrates the problem.

I set up this model:

```
class TestPoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pickup_location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

Then I run:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point, Polygon
>>> from mytest.models import TestPoint
>>> p1 = TestPoint(name="p1", pickup_location=Point(-118.4, 33.9))
>>> p2 = TestPoint(name="p2", pickup_location=Point(-118.45, 34))
>>> p3 = TestPoint(name="p3", pickup_location=Point(-118.3, 34.02))
>>> p4 = TestPoint(name="p4", pickup_location=Point(-118.46, 34.01))
>>> bbox = (-118.5, 34, -118, 34.5)
>>> poly = Polygon().from_bbox(bbox)
>>> poly.srid = 4326
>>> hits = TestPoints.objects.filter(pickup_location__within=poly)
>>> hits
<QuerySet []>
```

I'd expect `hits` to contain 3 points, but as you can see it's empty.

I wondered if perhaps they changed the order of coordinates in `from_bbox()`, but [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/) says it's still (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax).

What's going on?

Comment: You did not save your `TestPoint`s to the database.

Comment: Damn, you're right. This is actually a failing of my test example then. The actual code has the points in the database and it still fails. I'll try distilling the example from the actual code and will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not save your `TestPoint`s to the database. You save these with:

```
p1 = TestPoint.objects.create(name='p1', pickup_location=Point(-118.4, 33.9))
```

By using:

```
p1 = TestPoint(name="p1", pickup_location=Point(-118.4, 33.9))
```

you simply make a `TestPoint` *object* at the Django/Python layer, but you never put it in the database.